# How did "lambda" come to mean "average"?

Tags: étymologie

I've just learned that "lambda" has the additional meaning of "average" or something close to that, which I find surprising. How did it come to acquire this meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The Greek alphabet starts from "*alpha*" and ends with "*omega*". As for the lesser-known "*lambda*", it comes in the 11th place among all 24 letters.

The midpoint is the 12th/13th letters, to which "*lambda*" is placed closest, hence the idea of holding an "*average*" position in the grand scheme of things.

If you land at the 11th/12th/13th/14th spot out of 24 competitors, you will reasonably qualify as "*average/lambda*", being close to neither the victor "*alpha*" nor the "*omega*" finishing last.

I'd say something like:

> Une grande chance comme ça n'arrive qu'une seule fois dans la vie de quelqu'un ***lambda*** comme moi !

[image].

Comment: Merci, Monsieur. C'est cool.

Comment: So you're saying the French consider the 11lth letter closer to the position between the 12th and the 13th letter than either the 12th or the 13th?

Comment: @sgf Hi. Considering that "average" is a notion referring to **a certain range around the midpoint** instead of the exact midpoint, I find it just as logical to use the 11th letter as the 12th/13th. For instance, "an average age of 50" can represent a range of "45-55". So it does not necessarily have to be exactly 50 or the closest 49/51, but can also be 48/52 just as well to qualify as the notion of "**average/lambda**".

Comment: @sgf Yes, *polytechniciens* are well known to be bad at maths...

Comment: @sgf It might be because 12th and 13th places "mu" and "nu" both already mean something in French.

Answer (score 2):

Précisément, l'usage de lambda comme "moyen" provient de l'[école polytechnique](http://www.lajauneetlarouge.com/article/largot-de-lx-en-1938-jai-vu-le-gnass-dunablat-avec-un-chamo-cornecul)